# Open document after page load

Tags: asp.net

I would like to open a document after my ASP.NET page loads in a separate window.  I would like to do this with the document not attempt to be blocked by a pop-up blocked.  I tried and I am getting the prompt to ask if I would like to allow the popup.  Is the best way to do this using a timer control or is there a better way in the lifecylce?

I have tried several events, but they are all launching the document prior to page load.

Comment: Got some code? When do you load the document? How do you load the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally what you're trying to do is exactly the thing that pop-up blockers are designed to prevent - load a pop-up window without an explicit user interaction. There may be various tricks you could use to get around certain particular pop-up blockers, but you'll never be able to solve this in the general case.

The best solution is to have a link on your page to open the document in question in a new window. Pop-up blockers do not prevent links targeted to a new window.

Comment: Understood, but I still need to try to come up with something.

Comment: The problem is it's fundamentally a losing battle. Even if you find some hack that will work for one browser or add-in, countless others will still probably block the pop-up. Even if you managed to find something that worked against all of them, chances are the pop-up blocker would be updated and your page would fail to load.

Comment: Push back against the requirement. Every major browser comes with a popup blocker because users hate them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onload JavaScript event.

```
function open_page()
{ 
    popupWin = window.open('windowURL','windowName', ' resizable,dependent,status,width=500,height=400,left=0,top=0')
}
```

Then have the following body tag

```
<body onload="open_page()">
```

However, this won't get around your popup blocking issue.

Answer (score 0):

How are users getting to your page? You could place the popup JavaScript in the link that takes users to your page.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
function openpage(page) {
    if (document.getElementById('hf_open').value == 1) {
        openChild(page, 'nueva');
        document.getElementById('hf_open').value = 0;
    }
}
```

and in the body `onload ="openpage('whateverpage.aspx');"`
and in an ASP.NET event I set if I want the popup to be open or not a particular time by setting hf_open to 1 if the pop up has to be opened at that time.

In Internet Explorer 7 with pop up blocker: turn on checked - it works.